# Cannot set custom object property

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a javascript class JsonOptions. I do not understand why I am unable to set the OnSuccess property. My attempt to write it out in the ajaxJSON function is results in empty.

```
function JsonOptions()
{
    this.Url = "";
    this.OnSuccess = "";
}

function ajaxJSON(sender, e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = sender.href;
    var onsuccess = $(sender).attr('data-ajax-onsuccess');

    var options = new JsonOptions();
    options.Url = url;
    options.OnSucccess = onsuccess;
    //options.OnSucccess = "Setting a straight string";
    console.log('WORKS onsuccess ' + onsuccess);
    console.log('BLANK! o.OnSuccess ' + options.OnSuccess);
    //...ommitted
}
```

Oddly, `Url` works.

I tried to make a fiddle but could not replicate. Conflict somewhere? What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typo in line: `options.OnSucccess = onsuccess;`

You mean it should be `options.OnSuccess = onsuccess;`, you have 1 too many *c* in *"options.OnSuccess"*

Comment: I needed a friend to look over my shoulder. thank you.

Comment: @Valamas-AUS No worries, it happens :) Probably means time to take a break and grab a coffee.

Comment: Yeah, maybe using something like JSLint might help with errors like that.